# using v-for to make a css grid

Tags: css, vue.js

I want these images to appear horizontal instead of vertical on the preview. I tried applying the display grid in the css, but it still appears vertical. Can someone tell me what is missing? Basically try selecting two or more images and they appear vertical

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({ url: [], }),
  methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      [...e.target.files].forEach(f => this.url.push(URL.createObjectURL(f)))
    },
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

#app {
  padding: 20px;
}

#preview {

 
}
.flipper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}


#preview img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  padding-right:5px;
   display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.myGallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" multiple="multiple" @change="onFileChange" /><br>
  <div id="preview" v-for="(img, i) in url" :key="i" class=flipper>
    <img :src="img" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.flipper` class should be in element that wrap the elements rendered by `v-for` :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    url: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      [...e.target.files].forEach(f => this.url.push(URL.createObjectURL(f)))
    },
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

#app {
  padding: 20px;
}

#preview {}

.flipper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}

#preview img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.myGallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" multiple="multiple" @change="onFileChange" /><br>
  <div class="flipper">
    <div id="preview" v-for="(img, i) in url" :key="i">
      <img :src="img" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I want it to eventually stack on an additional row after it reaches x amount ?

Comment: the x amount is fixed by you?

Comment: Yes. Say it’s 6 images then go to next

Comment: You could  do `grid-template-columns: repeat(6 , 1fr);`

Comment: You're welcome, please don't forget to upvote my answer. here some useful websites to learn more https://learncssgrid.com/  https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

Make the style `display: inline-block` instead of `display: grid` for `.flipper` class will resolve the issue.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    url: ['a.jpg', 'b.jpg', 'c.jpg']
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

#app {
  padding: 20px;
}

.flipper {
  display: inline-block;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
}


#preview img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  padding-right:5px;
   display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}

.myGallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="preview" v-for="(img, i) in url" :key="i" class="flipper">
    <img :src="img" />
  </div>
</div>
```